# Can not load libcudnn.so.7 in jupyter notebook while I can load it when running in command line

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am able to load libcudnn.so.7 when I run the code in command line.
But I can't load it when run the same code in jupyter notebook (in the same conda virtual environment as when I ran in command line):

```
2020-12-06 14:25:30.551880: W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /volper/users/gaowang/fqx/my_cudnn/lib64
2020-12-06 14:25:30.551963: E external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:349] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

I have made sure the environment variables are exactly the same in two cases, including the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Do you have separate virtual envs? Same venv? Plain python installation + pip?

Comment: I am using the same conda environment in the case of command line and jupyter notebook.

Comment: Is it possible that you have both x86 and x86-64 pythons and jupyter launches different version?